# How to make infinite loop to keep the clock showing continuously for 8086?

Tags: loops, assembly, x86-16, processor, 16-bit

Following is the code that I have written but it shows the time once i want it to be in the loop to keep updating. I have tried .while loop and simple loops but they are not helping.

```
MAIN PROC

L1:
     mov cx, 100
     push cx

     MOV AX, @DATA                ; initialize DS
     MOV DS, AX


     mov BX,offset time           ; BX=offset address of string TIME

     CALL GET_TIME                ; call the procedure GET_TIME

     CALL clrscr

     MOV DX,offset time           ; DX=offset address of string PROMPT
     MOV AH, 09H                  ; print the string PROMPT
     INT 21H                                          

     MOV AH, 4CH                  ; return control to DOS
     INT 21H

     pop cx
     inc cx

     loop L1

MAIN ENDP
```

Comment: `MOV AH, 4CH                  ; return control to DOS` `INT 21H` exits your program so it doesn't reach the loop statement. Loop automatically decreases _CX_, Don't think you want that `inc cx` at all. and you need to move the `mov cx, 100` outside the loop above the label `L1`

Comment: Thankyou, It worked!